# Get main Router IP address, when there is a different gateway address

Tags: ios, objective-c

One of our apps needs to grab the Router IP and Mac address for submitting a ticket to our support team, I am having an issue as one of the services we provide to our customers, is a compression service to help them save on bandwidth.  This service works with the router, and thus, the gateway address, is the compression mechanism, and not the router itself.  All of the "Get gateway address" code examples I have found work, and successfully get the Gateway address, I also successfully see the router IP address in the ARP table.. however, it just appears another device in the ARP table.  Is there any way to pull the Router IP address when it is NOT the same as the Gateway IP address?  Generally in our setup, they are 1 IP address away from each other, but this is not guaranteed.

Comment: Is it possible to deploy some solution in the middle to retrieve and host this information for your app? If there are any limitations in the current architecture, I guess that can be a viable option (e.g., customize the router's management console to display this information on a web page, then you can retrieve it using some web application somewhere and make it available in xml/json format, etc.) -- I guess the tags for this question could include some networking knowledge as well, are you mostly interested in the obj-c code or how to retrieve the IP address considering the gateway issue?

Comment: The objective-c code, we do manufacture a router ourselves, and it does have a url I can hit that does provide that information, BUT, unfortunately all of our customers don't use our router, but still use other services of ours.